# Get parent URL from the_permalink();

Tags: php, wordpress, parent, permalinks

So here is my problem.
The Wordpress PHP function

```
the_permalink();
```

gives me this URL: http://www.website.com/author-20/article-title

I basically need his parent URL. How can I get it? ( http://www.website.com/author-20/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the link is always build that way you can cut out the part after the last `/`. The way to do that in PHP is with the functions `substr` and `strrpos`.

```
$parentUrl = substr($permaLink, 0, strrpos($permaLink, '/'));
```

`substr` cuts out a part of the string, beginning with the second parameter with the length of the third parameter.

`strrpos` searches for the last position of a character in a string.

If the link structure represents the post parent structure consider [this question from the wordpress stackexchange community](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/192895/get-parent-page-url-show-up-when-its-in-child-pages).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`dirname()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) for this.

```
$url = "http://www.website.com/author-20/article-title";
var_dump(dirname($url));
```

Output:

```
http://www.website.com/author-20
```